# Javascript variables and json keys

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access JSON values with dynamic keys.

Can you please help! I didn’t see what is wrong with my code.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name1":"John", "name2":"Bill", "name3":"Mos"}');

var names = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
  names[i] = "name" + i;
}

console.log(obj.name1);  // John  - which is fine

var myVar;
        
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    myVar = names[i];
    console.log(myVar);   // name1, name2 or name3
    console.log(obj.myVar);  // undefined - I need it to print, John, Bill or Mos
}
```

Comment: try ```console.log(obj[myVar])```, instead of ```console.log(obj.myVar)```.

Comment: Also, consider `Object.values(obj)` to just get the values.

Comment: thanks! works with console.log(obj[myVar])